# Tridion:ComponentPresentation embeded in the page - SDL web 8.5

Tags: web8, content-delivery, componentpresentation, deployer-conf

I have an issue with content within a Component Presentation (REL) not being displayed on a published page.
We are migrating from Tridion 2011 to SDL web 8.5, so, these component templates were working on previous version.

Let me explain the scenario:

I have a component template "Arlo2 Product Slides How" (tcm:97-45521-32)
[image]

which is rendering other components using this code:

```
<section class="product_slideshow @@CollectionLength("Component.Fields.products") > 3 ? 'long' : ''@@" arrows-t1">
<div class="container">
  <div class="slides ibp">
  <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="products" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation(Field, productslides)@@
  <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
  </div>
</div>
```

where "productslides" is a component template (97-45519-32) REL too..

[image]

When I browser the page generated by Tridion, i see this code embedded

```
 <section class="product_slideshow long" arrows-t1">      
    <div class="container">        
    <div class="slides ibp">      
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45591" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45593" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45588" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-46275" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45589" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45590" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>      
    </div>      
    </div>    
    </section>
```

as you can see, .NET was able to get the content of the first template (97-45521-32) because we are seeing html code there .. but, the other component presentations are not getting resolved.

I run a query to Tridion 2011 broker database to check the content of component presentation and I got this:

```
<section class="product_slideshow long" arrows-t1">      <div class="container">        <div class="slides ibp">            <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" componentURI="tcm:97-45591" templateURI="tcm:97-45519-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL" />            <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" componentURI="tcm:97-45593" templateURI="tcm:97-45519-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL" />            <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" componentURI="tcm:97-45588" templateURI="tcm:97-45519-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL" />            <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" componentURI="tcm:97-46275" templateURI="tcm:97-45519-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL" />            <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" componentURI="tcm:97-45589" templateURI="tcm:97-45519-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL" />            <tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" componentURI="tcm:97-45590" templateURI="tcm:97-45519-32" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.tridion.com/ContentDelivery/5.3/TCDL" />        </div>      </div>    </section>
```

same query to SDL web8.5 broker database:

```
<section class="product_slideshow long" arrows-t1">      <div class="container">        <div class="slides ibp">      <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server"     PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45591" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/><tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45593" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/><tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45588" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/><tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-46275" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/><tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45589" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/><tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:97-45594-16" ComponentURI="tcm:97-45590" TemplateURI="tcm:97-45519-32"/>      </div>      </div>    </section>
```

so, it looks like component presentations from @@rendercomponentpresentation@@ are saved as with .net tag instead tcdl,

do you have any idea why it is happening? Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix the problem making this change on tcdl-conf.xml

Old value:

```
<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="dotnet"/>
```

New value (this fixed the problem)

```
<Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="dotnet"/>
```